# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

im  new to React and I keep getting this error tried a few suggestions I found around but none seemed to work for me. Im guessing the error has to do with the way react compiles.It just **doesn't seem to find my "symbol" id** in the render method. Thanks in advance for the help.

**My Error**

App.js:101 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
at App.registerTrade (App.js:101)
at App.render (App.js:137)
at ReactCompositeComponent.js:793
at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:73)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:792)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:819)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:359)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:255)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:368)
```

**Here is my function**

```
registerTrade() {

      var contract = require('truffle-contract')
      var tradeRegistry = contract(tradeRegistryContract);
      var self = this;

      var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount")).value;
      var symbol = document.getElementById("symbol").value;

      this.setStatus("Registering trade... (please wait)");

      var meta; 

      tradeRegistry.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        meta = instance;
        return meta.registerSale(amount, symbol);
      }).then(function() {
        self.setStatus("Trade registered!");
      }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        self.setStatus("Error registering trade; see log.");
      });
    }
```

**the React render method**

```
render() {

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <nav className="navbar pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
              <a href="#" className="pure-menu-heading pure-menu-link">Trade Registry</a>
          </nav>



         <main className="container">
          <div className="pure-g">
            <div className="pure-u-1-1">
             <h1>Welcome</h1> 
             <br></br>
             <h3>Register your trade</h3>
             <br></br><label for="amount">Amount:</label><input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="e.g., $420"></input>
             <br></br><label for="symbol">Symbol:</label><input type="text" id="symbol" placeholder="e.g., TSLA"></input>
             <br></br><button id="send" onClick={this.registerTrade()}>Register Trade</button>
             <br></br>
             <span id="status"></span>
             <br></br>
             <br></br>
             <span id="block"></span>
             <br></br>
             <span id="evntAddress"></span>
             <span id="evntAmt"></span>
             <span id="evntSymbol"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>     

      );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are parsing the dom element instead of the value. Try:

```
var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount").value, 10);
```

Comment: Ty very much for the quick answer, but currently my error is with this line:


  <br></br><label for="symbol">Symbol:</label><input type="text" id="symbol" placeholder="e.g., TSLA"></input>


Sorry if my question wasn't specific enough editing for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to declare state variables and then call them from my HTML elements, like so.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {     
    inputAmt:'',   
    inputSym:''      
}

<br></br><label htmlFor="amount">Amount:</label><input value={this.state.inputAmt} onChange={amt => this.updateInputAmt(amt)} type="text" id='amount' placeholder="e.g., $420" />
<br></br><label htmlFor="symbol">Symbol:</label><input value={this.state.inputSym} onChange={sym => this.updateInputSym(sym)} type="text" id='symbol' placeholder="e.g., TSLA" />
```